# Deleting non matching words using for loop?

Tags: shell

Lets say I have a variable called `animals` that stores the following words.

```
cat
dog
bird
whale
```

And I have another variable called `delete` with one or more regexes that I am going to use to delete certain animals from the list.

If the delete variable contains only one regex, lets say `bird$` and I type

```
echo "$animals" | sed "/$delete/!d"
```

Then whats left in the animals variable is indeed just the word bird.

The problem appears when I want to remove several animals, meaning my delete variable has two or more regexes in it(separated by blank space).

Lets say the delete variable no contains: dog$ bird$.

I have written this for loop:

```
for i in $delete; do
 animals=$(echo "$animals" | sed "/$i/!d")
done
```

But this does not work. I think it is giving me a completely empty animals variable.

The opposite however: sed "/$i/d" works.

How can I remove the patterns not matching the regexes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the format of your `delete` variable from space separated to `|` (pipe) separated (meaning OR in regex syntax) you can do it in one sweep:

```
animals="cat
dog
bird
whale"

delete='dog$|bird$'
echo "$animals" | sed -r "/$delete/"'! d'
dog
bird
```

- note the funny quoting with both double and single quotes, due to bash interpretation of `!` inside double quotes

Comment: Could I change the format of the variable by replacing the blank spaces by pipe via some kind of command instead of manually?

Comment: @Daeto something like `delete=$(echo 'dog$ bird$'| sed 's/ /|/g')` would do the trick, but you have to adopt it to your situation.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works quite well but a problem appears if the names in the delete variable are separated by more than one blank space (in that case two pipes pop up and it stops working). Can anything be done about that?

Comment: @Daeto That problem would also appear with the your space separated approach (at least in the for loop). I would try to adopt your script at the place where the `delete` variable is concatenated together.

Comment: What do you mean adopt?

Comment: @Daeto, sorry I totally misunderstood your comment. Now I think, you need something like the sed command in `delete=$(echo 'dog$  bird$'| sed -r 's/[ ]+/|/g')`, which converts sequences of one ore more spaces to one pipe.

Answer (score 0):

You can't go through the list one by one because every word will fail to match one of the patterns and be removed.

You need to test against all of the patterns at the same time before deciding whether to remove the word. One way to do that would be using awk:

```
awk -v d="$delete" 'BEGIN { n = split(d, patterns) } 
{ for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) if ($0 ~ patterns[i]) { print; next } }' animals
```

We split the space-separate list of patterns into an array before processing the file. For each line of the file, we loop through the list and print any lines that match one of the patterns.